# Format Data for Statsmodels Linear Regression

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to do some multivariate linear regression using **Statsmodels** in Python, but I've been having a bit of a mental roadblock trying to organize my data.

So the default Boston dataset looks like this:

[image: Boston Housing Dataset]

And the output of the *linear regression model* is this:

[image: Linear Regression Output]

My raw data is space separated like so:

[image: Raw Data]

And I have been able to arrange it into the array here:

[image: Formatted Data Dictionary]

Does anyone with more Python experience know how I can format my data in a similar way to the Boston dataset so that I can easily preform my regression model? For instance, setting up `feature_names` that correspond to my data indices.

Here are the first several lines of my raw data for reference:

```
cycles         instructions   cache-references  cache-misses  branches     branch-misses  page-faults  Power
62,206,703     32,245,343     611,044           95,558        5,641,681    222,594        421          6.6
77,401,927     61,320,289     822,194           98,898        10,910,837   595,585        1,392        6.1
344,672,658    271,884,884    5,371,884         1,253,294     49,628,843   2,782,476      5,392        7.6
231,536,106    173,069,386    3,239,546         325,881       31,584,329   1,777,599      4,372        7.0
212,658,828    152,965,489    3,100,104         251,128       28,182,710   1,588,984      4,285        6.8
1,222,008,914  1,254,822,100  21,562,804        647,512       228,200,750  8,455,056      5,044        15.6
932,484,581    1,132,190,670  8,591,598         507,549       196,773,155  7,610,639      7,147        12.5
241,069,403    148,143,290    3,745,890         320,577       27,384,544   1,614,852      4,325        7.4
253,961,868    195,947,891    3,399,113         331,988       36,069,348   1,980,045      4,322        7.7
142,030,480    91,300,650     2,026,211         242,980       17,269,376   1,010,190      3,651        6.5
90,317,329     51,421,629     1,309,714         146,585       9,332,184    492,279        1,511        6.2
293,537,472    224,121,684    3,964,357         379,418       41,137,776   1,981,583      3,386        7.9
```

Thanks

Comment: From the second screenshot, it looks like you are modelling using statsmodels, not scikit-learn.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. I've been working with both and used the wrong name here.

Comment: Could you provide the first 10 lines of your raw data, including any eventual headers? (As text, not as a screenshot.)

Comment: Sure thing, just added it

Comment: And what are you trying to predict? "Power"?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to predict power based on these other performance counters

Comment: if your data is in a csv file, then just use pandas read_csv and you have it already in the correct format. (maybe with some special handling of the thousand comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `pandas` to read the data into memory and otherwise just follow the example you found on Boston housing prices:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', thousands=',')
X = df.loc[:, 'cycles':'page-faults']
y = df['Power']
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
```

In this case, `model.summary()` becomes

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  Power   R-squared:                       0.972
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.932
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     24.56
Date:                Fri, 10 Nov 2017   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00139
Time:                        22:09:47   Log-Likelihood:                -21.470
No. Observations:                  12   AIC:                             56.94
Df Residuals:                       5   BIC:                             60.33
Df Model:                           7                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
====================================================================================
                       coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cycles            1.287e-07   5.11e-08      2.518      0.053   -2.66e-09     2.6e-07
instructions     -7.083e-09   4.21e-07     -0.017      0.987   -1.09e-06    1.07e-06
cache-references -1.625e-06   2.48e-06     -0.656      0.541   -7.99e-06    4.74e-06
cache-misses      3.222e-06   5.24e-06      0.615      0.566   -1.03e-05    1.67e-05
branches          1.281e-07    2.6e-06      0.049      0.963   -6.55e-06    6.81e-06
branch-misses    -1.625e-05    1.2e-05     -1.357      0.233    -4.7e-05    1.45e-05
page-faults          0.0016      0.002      0.924      0.398      -0.003       0.006
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.485   Durbin-Watson:                   1.641
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.289   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.787
Skew:                           0.606   Prob(JB):                        0.675
Kurtosis:                       3.326   Cond. No.                     1.92e+06
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The condition number is large, 1.92e+06. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems.'
```